# On Duplicate Key Update insert record every time

Tags: mysql

I'm using this mysql query

```
insert into table (vin,name,city,dob) values ('der12','john','city name','2016-17-10')  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='john'
```

table structure is

```
id - bigint -primary key
vin - varchar 
name - varchar
city - varchar
dob - varchar
```

So here i have id as bigint and autoincreament , and vin also can't be duplicate , what i need is to check is
if the vin is already in table , update the record or do nothing if everything is the same , if vin is diffrent just 
insert the record.

i tried making vin as unique too but as

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD UNIQUE (vin)
```

but problem is after adding when i run the query it shows some duplicacy error instead of updating or ignoring it .

Need kind help .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your insert on duplicate works fine given the information provided. When you run a show create table <your table> do you see any other unique keys? And have you checked any triggers to see if they may be causing a duplicate elsewhere in your DB?

Comment: no i don't have any other unique keys .  just i want is insert if vin not present if vin present ignore or update .

Comment: As i said your query works fine for me - What exactly is the duplicate error and have you checked triggers?

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1062 - Duplicate entry '83762347' for key 'vin'                                           if i run the query twice . And thank for guiding me .

Comment: can you help please .

Comment: Sorry no - the only way I can replicate your issue is if I don't use the on duplicate clause. Have you checked that 83762347 actually exists in the DB (or possibly a truncated version of it) ? I did find a reference in the docs relating to the max varchar size - "The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used." but this seems a long shot and I didn't entirely understand it.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood, you want to add record if "vin" is different else keep previous record as it is.

You can get count of records having "vin" as "john" or anything value you are inserting currently. If count is "0", insert the record else do nothing.

Comment: yes that is possible , check if vin exist , if exist in table , if exist update that record else insert , but is that possible with a single query as i have more then 18 millions record.

Comment: check this: INSERT newtable (user,age,os) SELECT table1.user,table1.age,table2.os FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.user=table2.user;

Comment: try such queries in your case, it might help you